# show dynamic histogram using d3.js, node.js, postgresql

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, express, d3.js

I fetch the data from postgresql database using node.js and I showed this data in array form in my browser perfectly. I also showed static histogram (made in d3.js code) using node.js. The histogram also uses static array values. Both database values and a static histogram is showed separately on my browser page. Now what I want to do is to make this histogram dynamic so that the histogram uses the database values. I don't have idea how to assign database values to histogram?

I try it with simple node.js but not works.

```
/**
 * Created by Raees Afridi on 8/17/2015.*/

var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
var pg = require('pg');
var conString = "pg://postgres:raees@localhost:5432/tweetdb";

function onRequest(req, res) {

    if(req.method == 'GET' && req.url == '/') {

        res.writeHead(200, {"Context-Type": "text/html"});
        var client = new pg.Client(conString);
        client.connect();
        var query = client.query("SELECT t_follower, t_text FROM columbia ORDER BY t_follower desc limit 4");
        query.on("row", function (row, result) {
            result.addRow(row);
        });
        query.on("end", function (result) {
            var mydata = res.end(JSON.stringify(result.rows, null, "    "));
            console.log(mydata);
            client.end();
        });

        fs.createReadStream("./index.html").pipe(res);

    }





}

http.createServer(onRequest).listen(3000);
console.log("Server is running...")
```

Than I try it with express framework with the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title><%= title %></title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/style.css' />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.6/d3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <style>
        .pumpkin {
            fill: yellow;
            stroke: orange;
            stroke-width: 5;
        }
    </style>

</head>
<body>
<% include templates/header.ejs%>
<h3><%= title %> Page</h3>
<% root = JSON.parse( tweetdata ); %>
<ul>
    <% root.forEach(function(item) { %>
    <li><%= item.t_friends %></li>
    <% })%>
</ul>



    <% var dataset = Array(); var i=0; %>
    <% root.forEach(function(item) { %>
    <% dataset[i] = parseInt(item.t_friends); %>
    <% i+=1; }); %>
<% var dataset = dataset %>
<script type="text/javascript">

   // var dataset = [ 5, 10, 13, 19, 21, 25, 22, 18, 15, 13,
 //11, 12, 15, 20, 18, 17, 16, 18, 23, 25 ];
</script>


<script type="text/javascript">

    //Width and height
    var w = 500;
    var h = 100;
    var barPadding = 1;
   // var dataset = [ 5, 10, 13, 19, 21, 25, 22, 18, 15, 13,
       // 11, 12, 15, 20, 18, 17, 16, 18, 23, 25 ];

    //var dataset = tweetdata;

    //Create SVG element
    var svg = d3.select("body")
            .append("svg")
            .attr("width", w)
            .attr("height", h);

    svg.selectAll("rect")
            .data(dataset)
            .enter()
            .append("rect")
            .attr("x", function(d, i) {
                //return i * 21;    //Bar width of 20 is already defined and plus 1 for padding
                return i * (w / dataset.length);
            })
            .attr("y", function(d) {
                return h - (d * 4);
            })
            .attr("width", w / dataset.length - barPadding)
        //.attr("height", 100);
            .attr("height", function(d) {
                return d * 4;
            })
            .attr("fill", function(d) {
                return "rgb(0, 0, " + (d * 10) + ")";
            });

    svg.selectAll("text")
            .data(dataset)
            .enter()
            .append("text")
            .text(function(d) {
                return d;
            })
            .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
            .attr("x", function(d, i) {
                return i * (w / dataset.length) + (w / dataset.length - barPadding) / 2;
            })
            .attr("y", function(d) {
                return h - (d * 4) + 14;
            })
            .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
            .attr("font-size", "11px")
            .attr("fill", "white");

</script>



</body>
</html>
```

Any Idea?

Comment: Hi, can you post your code or a link to your project repo if you have one?

Comment: I am using express framework. I also tried it on simple node.js 

`</head>
<body>
<% include templates/header.ejs%>
<h3><%= title %> Page</h3>
<% root = JSON.parse( tweetdata ); %>
<ul>
    <% root.forEach(function(item) { %>
    <li><%= item.t_friends %></li>
    <% })%>
</ul>>    <% var dataset = Array(); var i=0; %>
    <% root.forEach(function(item) { %>
    <% dataset[i] = parseInt(item.t_friends); %>
    <% i+=1; }); %>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var svg = d3.select("body")
            .append("svg")
            .attr("width", w)
            .attr("height", h);`

Comment: Update the question with the code, not in a comment. It's unreadable.

Comment: @Michelem, thanks, Is it fine now?

Answer (score 0):

I would create a separate rest service to retrieve your data rather than sending it in your root request.

This way you can return a json object that d3 can use for the chart. 
(you are currently returning a string, I think this is the main reason your chart isn't rendering).

d3 has a method to get json from a rest service so you can use this to retrieve the data and render your chart once the data is returned.

I'm using the node.js example from your post but you may want to look into express routing to handle your services:

```
if(req.method == 'GET' && req.url == '/getchartdata') {
    var client = new pg.Client(conString);
    client.connect();
    var query = client.query("SELECT t_follower, t_text FROM columbia ORDER BY t_follower desc limit 4");
    query.on("row", function (row, result) {
        result.addRow(row);
    });
    query.on("end", function (result) {
        res.status(200)
        res.json(result.rows);
        client.end();
    });


}
```

Then in your script:

```
 //Width and height
    var w = 500;
    var h = 100;
    var barPadding = 1;
 //Create SVG element
    var svg = d3.select("body")
        .append("svg")
        .attr("width", w)
        .attr("height", h);

 d3.json('/getchartdata', function(error, dataset) {

        svg.selectAll("rect")
        .data(dataset)
        .enter()
        .append("rect")
        .attr("x", function(d, i) {
            //return i * 21;    
            //Bar width of 20 is already defined and plus 1 for padding
            return i * (w / dataset.length);
        })
        .attr("y", function(d) {
            return h - (d * 4);
        })
        .attr("width", w / dataset.length - barPadding)
      //.attr("height", 100);
        .attr("height", function(d) {
            return d * 4;
        })
        .attr("fill", function(d) {
            return "rgb(0, 0, " + (d * 10) + ")";
        });

        svg.selectAll("text")
        .data(dataset)
        .enter()
        .append("text")
        .text(function(d) {
            return d;
        })
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
        .attr("x", function(d, i) {
            return i * (w / dataset.length) + (w / dataset.length - barPadding) / 2;
        })
        .attr("y", function(d) {
            return h - (d * 4) + 14;
        })
        .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
        .attr("font-size", "11px")
        .attr("fill", "white");

  });
```